# Python import calls initializes parameters for __init__

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to do some simple dependency injection in Python. For example:

*logic.py*

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a = A()):
        self.a = a
```

So A() is being called as a default argument to B()

*main.py*

```
from logic import B #this calls A()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("main") # No concrete call to B() or A()
```

output:

> A
>
> main

Could anyone explain why `A()` is called, if all I did was to import `B`? Why would calling import `B` run the `__init__` of `A`?

By the way, to solve it all it takes is to change the `__init__` to:

```
class B(object):
   def __init__(self, a = None):
       if not a:
           a = A()
       self.a = a
```

Comment: Not exactly the same case. It's not about A being mutable or not, it's about A being called in the first place, or am I missing anything?

Comment: The answers to that question answer your question. `A()` is being evaluated and called *while `B.__init__` is being defined*, i.e. at "parse time". See the duplicate for many answers as to *why*.